# I want to run a python file from php. The python file contains many package (such as torch, models etc.)

Tags: python, php, apache2, shell-exec

I want to run a python file from PHP. The python file contains many packages (such as torch, models, etc.). I can easily run it using the command line but while calling it from PHP using shell_exec it does not run.

The php files looks somewhat likes this:

```php
$output = exec ('cd /home/prabhakar/Hackathon/Text_Speech/ ; conda activate neural_tts ; python quick_start.py -u --input_text "Hi?" ');
    echo $output."<br>";<br>
```

python file is:

```py
    import torch
    from models.fatchord_version import WaveRNN
    from utils import hparams as hp
    from utils.text.symbols import symbols
    from models.tacotron import Tacotron
    import argparse
    from utils.text import text_to_sequence
    from utils.display import save_attention, simple_table
    import zipfile, os


    os.makedirs('quick_start/tts_weights/', exist_ok=True)
    os.makedirs('quick_start/voc_weights/', exist_ok=True)

    zip_ref = 
    zipfile.ZipFile('pretrained/ljspeech.wavernn.mol.800k.zip', 'r')
    zip_ref.extractall('quick_start/voc_weights/')
    zip_ref.close()

    zip_ref = 
    zipfile.ZipFile('pretrained/ljspeech.tacotron.r2.180k.zip', 'r')
    zip_ref.extractall('quick_start/tts_weights/')
    zip_ref.close()


    if __name__ == "__main__":
        print("Hello World!!")
        exit()
```

Comment: Is there any more information you can provide?

Answer (score -1):

You might be using virtual environment. Try first activating the virtual environment through PHP and then running the python code.

Comment: This is the code that I have actually written inside PHP file. When I run the command separately on the terminal it works perfectly fine, but when I execute through php it doesn't give anything. Any suggestions?? $output = exec ('cd /home/prabhakar/Hackathon/Text_Speech/ ; conda activate neural_tts ; python quick_start.py -u --input_text "Hi?" ');